# How to recode values in a matrix based on a calculation?

Tags: r, data.table, calculation, recode

I have a question. I'm working on building a recommendation system in R, and I'm fairly new to the language. I can't seem to figure the following out.

I have a matrix like:

```
eventID g_26 g_27 g_28 g_29 g_30 g_31 g_32 g_33 g_34 g_35 g_36 g_37 g_38 g_39 g_40 g_41 g_42 g_43
1:    1010    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
2:    1016    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
3:    1019    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
4:    1053    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
5:    1168    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
6:    1188    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

What I´d like to do is replace all values that have 1 to 1/sqrt(total # of 1's in that particular row).

I'm using the Data Table package as well if that makes it easier.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` (`-1` implies we selected all the columns except the first column), get the sum of each row in the Subset of Data.table with `Reduce` and `+`, take the square root (`sqrt`), divide by 1, multiply with the Subset of data.table (`.SD`) and assign (`:=`) it to the columns of interest

```
dt[, (2:ncol(dt)) := .SD*1/sqrt(Reduce(`+`, .SD)), .SDcols = -1]
```

Comment: Akrun, please do not copy paste my answers with minimal changes. You had a for loop there. Explore your creativity.

Comment: @RonakShah It is not your answer.  Please check

Comment: I am well aware of all your tricks. Please see your edit revision if you have a doubt what I am talking about.

Comment: @RonakShah  May be I just copy/pasted the wrong one.

Comment: Nice solution, this works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can multiply the dataframe with the value.

All the numbers that are 0 will remain 0 and the one with 1's will get changed to the desired output

```
df[-1] * 1/sqrt(rowSums(df==1))
```

Comment: This seems to work, however, it also changes all the 1's in my eventID column (eg. id # 1010 will count as two 1's since its numerical. Any change to avoid this column?

Comment: @StefanMusch I have ignored that by using index `-1` in `df`. It will ignore the first column in the dataframe.

Comment: @StefanMusch  I posted a data.table answer.  Please check it.  It doesn't have that problem

Answer (score 0):

As an example

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ncol = 3, byrow = T)

rs <- apply(m,1,sum)
rs <- sqrt(rs)

m <- m/rs
```

Hope that's helpful